# Collection of Actions

Tags: c#, casting, callback

I am trying to create a class to queue up a series of commands. (Not really a queue as events happen based on time). Each command has a callback (Action) that get's called. However, each Action has a different set of parameters (signature), so I am using an object[] to pass them and then have to do lots of casting.

Example: the Queue class:

```
class RfxQueue {
    public enum CMD {DISPLAY, REPLACE_TMPLT, SCALE_DVE, etc };
    private Dictionary<CMD, Action<object []>> actions = new Dictionary<CMD,Action<object[]>>();
    // Struct to hold command info
    public struct QItem
    {
        public CMD cmd;           // The CMD to exec
        public long ttd;          // Time to be executed
        public object[] param;    // Parameters to Action
    }
    private List<QItem> q = new List<QItem>();   // The queue of events

    // Create a new callback
    public void addAction(CMD cmd, Action<object []> action)
    {
        actions.Add(cmd, action);
    }

    // Add to Q
    public void pushEvent(CMD Cmd, float Delay, params object[] Param)
    {
        q.Add(new QItem() { cmd = Cmd, param = Param, ttd = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(Delay * 1000).Ticks });
    }

    // This is actually done in a thread. Simplified here
    private void execEvent()
    {
        QItem item;
        // item is pulled from q here
        actions[item.cmd].Invoke(item.param);
    }
}
```

And the owner class creates events like this:

```
// "q" is a RfxQueue and the internal Invoke is required to run on main thread
q.events.Add(RfxQueue.CMD.SCALE_DVE, new Action<object[]>(o =>
{
    dispatcher.Invoke(new Action<string, string, bool>((a,b,c) =>
    {
        _cgManager.ScaleDVE(a, b, c);
    }), (string)o[0], (string)o[1], (bool)o[2]);
}));
q.events.Add(RfxQueue.CMD.PLAY_ANIMATION, new Action<object[]>(o =>
{
    dispatcher.Invoke(new Action<VideoTemplate, string>((v, s) => {
        _cgManager.playAnimation(v, s);
    }), (VideoTemplate)o[0], (string)o[1]);
}));
```

Lastly, an event is added like this:

```
// Play animation "inserton" in 3 seconds
q.add(RfxQueue.CMD.PLAY_ANIMATION, template, 3f, "inserton");
```

Is there a way to do this without all that casting? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting from minor issues - please follow naming conventions (variables should be camelCased and methods PascalCased, do add access modifiers, give variables meaningful names).

Your design breaks [Open-Closed principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle): Queue knows all the possible commands it can handle. In case when you need to add a new command you'll have to change the queue rather than add new code.

Also it breaks [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) since queue knows not only about scheduling the execution but also serves as a repository for all possible actions to be run for commands.

Both issues as well as those you have mentioned (type casting, different signatures) can be easily solved if you create a separate class per command type. Command will encapsulate parameters required for execution as well as the action to be executed:

```
public interface ICommand
{
    void Execute();
}

public class ScaleDveCommand : ICommand
{
    public CgManager CgManager { get; set; }
    public string FirstString { get; set; } //TODO:Rename to meaningful name
    public string SecondString { get; set; } //TODO:Rename to meaningful name
    public bool SomeBool { get; set; } //TODO:Rename to meaningful name

    public void Execute()
    {
        dispatcher.Invoke(() => CgManager.ScaleDVE(FirstString, SecondString, SomeBool));
    }
}

public class PlayAnimationCommand : ICommand
{
    public CgManager CgManager { get; set; }
    public VideoTemplate VideoTemplate { get; set; }
    public string SomeMeaningfulNameHere { get; set; } //TODO:Rename to meaningful name

    public void Execute()
    {
        dispatcher.Invoke(() => { CgManager.playAnimation(VideoTemplate, SomeMeaningfulNameHere); });
    }
}
```

And your "queue" class will look like:

```
public class RfxQ
{
    private readonly SortedList<long, ICommand> _queue = new SortedList<long, ICommand>();   // The queue of events

    public void PushEvent(ICommand command, TimeSpan delay)
    {
        _queue.Add(DateTime.Now.Add(delay).Ticks, command);
    }

    // This is actually done in a thread. Simplified here
    private void ExecEvent()
    {
        ICommand command;
        // item is pulled from _queue here
        command.Execute();
    }
}
```

And usage will look like:

```
q.pushEvent(new PlayAnimationCommand
    {
        CgManager = _cgManager,
        VideoTemplate = template,
        SomeMeaningfulNameHere = "inserton"
    }, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
```

Comment: So, basically you're saying that it's better to couple the action and its parameters? I'm not completely sure about that.

Comment: OOP defines class as a structure that combines state and behavior, so I don't see issue in coupling action (behavior) with parameters of that action (state).

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer. The only changes I will make are 1) making CgManager and dispatcher static vars in ICommand (making ICommand a class), and 2) have each command accept the parameters in their constructors. These will shorten calles to PushEvent. Will this break OO design?

Comment: Why would you make ICommand a class?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp It's hard to suggest the best approach actually since I don't know how CgManager and Dispatcher are managed. I generally dislike static fields (except static readonly ones) as it is a possible headache in multithreading environment as well as makes unit testing harder. Accepting parameters in constructor is fine.